# disabling browser context menu on a raphael paper

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a Raphael paper defined as `R1 = Raphael(0,0, 800, 600);`

I want to disable context menu on this paper so that I can catch mouse right click event. I don't have it like `Raphael("someDiv", 800, 600)` to disable the oncontextmenu property for the div.

How should I do it in this case?

Comment: Why are you trying to catch the right click?

Comment: So that he can disable Raphael's context menu. I'm guessing this could be related: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/AeU2r/

Comment: I want to perform some operation when right button is clicked on the paper. but it opens the context menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj.node.oncontextmenu = function(){ return false; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6tyH/

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching this:

```
/*[Your Element Here]*/.oncontextmenu = function(event){event.preventDefault();}
```

Catching `oncontextmenu` instead of right click.

Also note that the browser's preferences may not allow you to disable contextual menus.

Comment: I have and object like: var obj = paper.rect....  then I added the above method to obj.oncontextmenu... but it doesn't work.

Comment: How can I then tell it to do some operation if it is right click?