# Raphael: disable default context menu on right click not working

Tags: javascript, raphael

Following the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257535/disabling-browser-context-menu-on-a-raphael-paper) I'm trying to disable the default browser context menu and display instead a custom menu. As you can see in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/8Zy3F/1/), on right click the rect is displayed however the default menu shows up. I tried with both Chrome and IE and the behavior is the same. What's wrong with this code?

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#canvas {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
    var menu = null;
    var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas'), 500, 500);
    var rect2 = paper.rect(100, 100, 180, 180 ).attr({"fill" : "green" });

    rect2.node.oncontextmenu = function(){ return false; }

    rect2.mousedown(function(e) {

        if ( e.which != 3 ) // only allow right click
            return;

        menu = paper.rect ( e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 100, 100).attr({stroke: '#000000', fill:'#c2c2c2',"stroke-width":1});
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel the default action

```
function eventHandler(e){
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e.stopPropagation)
        e.stopPropagation();
    if(e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble = false;

    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Zy3F/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/tSGC5/